# Using static array inside class

Tags: c++

Inside Myclass.h

```
Class Myclass
{
public:
Myclass();
private:
static int Myarray[12];
};
```

How to initialize the above static array ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to *define* it exactly once, in a `.cpp` file:

```
int MyClass::MyArray[12] = { 0, 1, 2 }; /* Definition and initialisation.
                                           Any elements not explicity
                                           initialised will be 
                                           value-initialised,
                                           0 in the case of int. */
```

The posted code is only a *declaration* of the array.

Comment: Now MyArray[0] = 0 , MyArray[1] = 1 , MyArray[2] = 2 ...What is the value going to be stored in rest of the places .

Comment: @vivek, see comment in answer.

Comment: @hmjd, the rest of the values will be 0.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall, I KNOW! Its in the code comment in my answer.

Comment: @hmjd, sorry, I didn't refresh comments before posting.

Comment: After applying the above code it gives the following compilation error error C2369: 'MyArray': redefinition; different subscripts

But When i am doing as follows it will not show any error ..
int MyClass::MyArray[] = { 0, 1, 2 }; 

could anyone justify it ?

Comment: @vivek, that should be fine: http://ideone.com/LEko6 (and checked with VC10 and VC9). What compiler? Double-check the array size in both uses.

Comment: @vivek, I just compiled my example fine with VC8 (VS2005). Make sure you have saved and changes you made, both arrays have the same size, perform a clean and rebuild (just to be sure).

Answer (score 0):

Like Viku said:
You need to define it exactly once, in a .cpp file:

```
int MyClass::MyArray[12] = { 0, 1, 2 };
```

and you also need this declare it in your class.h private field
private:

```
static int MyArray[12];
```